# Nativescript localization testing using Appium - text extraction

Tags: testing, localization, appium, nativescript

I'm currently trying to figure out a good way to test localization of an app and have some trouble accessing the label text of a button UIElement after i've accessed the element by automation text. After accessing the button UIElement i'm only able to get the automationText to test against.
It's my first time doing any form of testing with nativescript, appium and mocha and i might go about it completely wrong and if so advise would be much appreciated.

What i'm testing on
- iPad simulator (9.7 inch) with OS v. 12.4
- node v10.16.3
- npm v6.9.0
- {N} v. 6.0.1
- runtimes v 6.0.1
- nativescript-localize for i18n localization

I've followed setup instructions and found some issues here where people hadn't installed carthage, which i've installed.

A simple test looks something like this

```
const daDK = require(dk.default.json); // localization file for danish  
const changeUserButton = await driver.findElementByAutomationText('changeUserButton');
expect(await changeUserButton.text()).to.be.equal(daDK.user.change_user);
```

**The problem:**

> Doing a log of the await changeUserButton.text() retreives the *automationText = changeUserButton*  where it should have been the text property with the value: *Skift Bruger*.

I've also tried to access elements in different way ie. with findElementByXPath and findElementByText (though i've read text is only android).

Any suggestions as to solve this?

I've also made an issue with even more details on nativescript-dev-appium Git repo [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-appium/issues/260)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean, `changeUserButton.text()` returns automationText instead of text?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Sorry if this wasn't entirely clear, will edit the original message for clearification.